# setVisibility(int) in android works after delay

Tags: android

Hey guys I'm trying to make an image appear on the touch of a button by using

```
Myimage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Here is part of the code :

```
case R.id.button5:
               if(myRandom == 5 )
                {
                   Myimage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    MediaPlayer mp =  MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.music);
                    mp.start();
                    while(mp.isPlaying())
                    {

                    }
                    found = true;

                }
                else

                 b5.setVisibility(View.GONE);
               break;
```

Now for b5 which is a view for a button the function works fine, the button disapears.
For Myimage however getvisibility() tells me it is == visible but i cant see it on the screen, i can only see it after the switch statement is over
Any thoughts?

I have tried defining a function as such so that tit runs on a seperate thread but i have the same problem of the image not appearing.

```
   public void startplayer()
       {
           Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
               public void run() {
                   mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.fart);
                   mp.start();
                   while(mp.isPlaying())
                   {

                   }
               }
           });
           thread.start();
```

Thanks.

I ended up getting it working with :

```
 new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.donkey);
                       mp.start();
                       while(mp.isPlaying())
                       {

                       }


                    finish();
                }
            }, 0);
```

Comment: Guess you are blocking the UI Thread.

Comment: Put `Myimage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);` to your `onCreate()` method, as default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you block the UI thread by running this code on the UI thread:

```
MediaPlayer mp =  MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.music);
mp.start();
while(mp.isPlaying())
{

}
```

The code above will basically behave like an *infinite loop* on UI thread as long as your MediaPlayer object is playing. You should post this block of code onto a background thread instead, or at least the "while(mp.isPlaying())" part.

Comment: I have tried to follow your advice in the edit any idea why this does not work?

Comment: I see that you have it working, so this is just a suggestion: if you just need to post the runnable to the next UI cycle, you can simple use View#postDelayed(java.lang.Runnable, long) rather than creating a new Handler. However, the code you have will still block the UI thread when the MediaPlay object is playing, so it's still not good practice. You can verify what I said by having another button and try to tap on that button (this button can just change it text or print log to console when being tapped). You'll see that the button is not responsive.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, as you can see i'm new to this. I also might have not been very clear, what i wanted was for the image to be displayed and the sound to run and nothing else to be possible. It's a "You won" type of animation... is what i have sensible in that case?

Comment: If I was to implement your problem ("You won" type of animation), I would still play the sound in the background and disable user interaction on the UI thread (e.g. View#setEnabled(false)). The main thing you need to keep in mind is that "never ever block the UI thread". Your solution will work for now, but if your boss comes and says: "I want to allow users to skip the animation by giving them an X button", then it won't work anymore, right :)

Answer (score 1):

This probably happens because you block the UI thread with your while loop.
You should never do long operations or wait on the main thread.

To understand better why the main thread should be kept free, read the official [docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html#Threads)

In your specific case you should implement a callback.
Just do

```
mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
    override void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        // Here you recieve the callback even.
    }
})
```

What callbacks do (and get used to them in android), is notify you when something happens. So now instead of waiting for the player to finish playing by yourself - you just get notified when it happens.
Remember - the MediaPlayer knows when it stopped playing, you shouldn't do it's job for him.
[A nice blogpost with more info on callbacks](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077462/learn-java/java-tip-10--implement-callback-routines-in-java.html)

Every time you are thinking about doing a `while(true)` loop, think again - something is wrong.

Comment: Hey i'm not sure  i understand what the callback is or what it accomplishes...Would you mind giving me a little more detail?